# function is not defined, when it is

Tags: javascript, node.js

today i was working on a project, and i got this error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: launch is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (home.html:77)

i don't understand what i did wrong here..
Here is the index.js file:

```
function launch() {
  console.log('test');
}
  

module.exports.launch = launch;
```

and home.html:

```
<script>
    let func  = require('./index');

    let launch = func.launch();

    document.getElementById('lanBTN').addEventListener('click', () => {
      launch();
    });

   <input type="button" value="Launch!" id="lanBTN" onclick="launch()">
  </script>
```

Any ideas why this is happening..?

Comment: Should be `let launch = func.launch`. No parentheses, so that you don't invoke it.

Comment: You are trying to use `module.exports` (a node module) in your client side. why not just `<script src='...'></script>`. This seems wrong

Comment: I am a bit confused, where script tags, and HTMLInputElement come from in a nodejs context, without electron.

Comment: Could be JSDOM, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@mehdi-belbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7896308/mehdi-belbal) mentioned you can not use CommonJS in HTML files expect if when using module bundlers like Webpack.
Besides of that module.exports is useless here, try to link your javascript module in the `head` of the document. and the declared function after. that will attach to the window object and you can use them both by using `window.func()` and ‍`func()`

```
<head>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    func();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you replaced `func` with `launch`? that was just an example to show.

Comment: and remove `onclick` attribute from your element. there is no need for using attributes when attaching listener with `addEventListener`.

Comment: yeah, i did. I tried both  window.launch(); and just  launch(); . Still got the same error

Comment: Can you create a Codesandbox?

Comment: yeah, 1 second!

Comment: Just for the html, or also the index.js ?

Comment: here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/black-mountain-49g0n?file=/index.html

Comment: I added a launch function in the js file and it's just working fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-sammet-mt5tp?file=/index.html

Comment: OH, i saw what i did wrong, thanks everything works now!

Answer (score 1):

Require is a commonjs module specification, it doesn't work on the browser unless you use some bundler like webpack or browserify to resolve the dependencies between all of you modules and bundles one single js file to include in your html